# Cuál es el valor de un número ingresado en un input python sin castear, entiendo que debo agregar un cast al input pero si no lo agrego como queda¿

Tags: python, input, cast

```
#Variable que almacena peso en gramos por cada payaso
payaso = 112

#Se ingresa cantidad de payasos a enviar
cantidad_p = input("Ingrese cantidad de payasos a enviar: ")

#Se calcula cantidad peso total de payasos segun su cantidad
total_p = cantidad_p * payaso

#Variable que almacena peso en gramos por cada muñeca
munecas = 75

#Se ingresa cantidad de payasos a enviar
cantidad_m = input("Ingrese cantidad de muñecas a enviar: ")

#Se calcula cantidad peso total de muñecas segun su cantidad
total_m = cantidad_m * munecas

#Total final de peso entre total payasos y muñecas 
total_final = total_p + total_m

#Se imprime cantidad final en pantalla
print("La cantidad final total del peso entre payasos y muñecas es de: ", str(total_final))
```

Comment: Buen día, por defecto el tipo de dato de los `input` es `string`

Comment: @HeytalePazguato no es por default, la función input SIEMPRE devuelve una cadena, y no hay forma de cambiar eso en Python.

Comment: @DanteS., gracias por la aclaración, lo que quise decir es que si no hay  `type-casting`, por defecto se obtiene un `string` pero tu frase lo explica mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber eso, puedes hacer uso de `type()` para saber el tipo de datos que agarra por defecto, algo como:

```
cantidad_p = input("Ingrese cantidad de payasos a enviar: ")

print(type(cantidad_p))
```

Y como respuesta a esto obtendrás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Existe una cosa llamada documentación. La puedes consultar en el sitio de [Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/functions.html#input). Fijate que hasta viene en castellano.

De acuerdo con la documentación:

**input([prompt])**

> Si el argumento prompt está presente, se escribe a la salida estándar
> sin una nueva línea a continuación. La función lee entonces una línea
> de la entrada, la convierte en una cadena (eliminando la nueva línea),
> y retorna eso. Cuando se lee EOF, se lanza una excepción EOFError.